# Pass Byte Array that was in Session object to a Web Service (Asp.Net 2.0 asmx) through a JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have a code:

Session["timestamp"] has a byte array in it coming using LInq to Entity

Now when i call this function it throws an error

The web service has a signature like:

```
[WebMethod]
public  string IsRowChanged(int en_id , byte[] timestamp)
{
}
```

If I replace byte[] with string everywhere it works.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "UpdateEntityService.asmx/IsRowChanged",
    data: "{ 'en_id':'" + '<%= Request.QueryString["entity_id"] == null ? "1" : Request.QueryString["entity_id"] %>' + "' , 'timestamp': '" + '<%= (Session["timestamp"]) %>' + "'   }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {

        var result = msg.d;

        if (result == "0") {

            save_valid();

            $.prompt("Data Saved Sucessfully");

        }
        else {

            $.prompt("Data Concurrency Error! Reload the Page.. by pressing F5");

        }

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the alert i get "error" in the message boxes. I am not getting any detail message. Even i dont know whether the byte array are passed the say way as the string.So that might be the issue

Comment: why don't you put a debugger and check whether the function gets called? also have you checked on firebug to see you response to the call?

Comment: @naveen i dont know hot to use debugger for response call. I will google it.Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should Base encode binary data and convert it back to byte[] at serverside.

```
// returns a byte[]
System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
// returns a string
System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
```

Comment: Is it possible that you can post a code for convert a byte[] to binary data so that i put it in a session object. and then revert back it. What should be the signature of my Web Method too

Comment: @KamalDeepSingh Post edited... If that don't work for you, let me know

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Pass it as string and convert it to ByteArray inside the function

```
[WebMethod]
public  string IsRowChanged(int en_id , string ts)
{
    byte[] timestamp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ts);
    // rest of your function here
}
```

And if you don't know the encoding type, use this function

```
private byte[] ConvertStringToBytes(string input)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(input);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Namespace used : `using System.IO;`

The point is, whichever encoding you are using, use the same decoding method to retrieve it. Here is an example for ASCII encoding / decoding

At your page encode like this.

```
string value = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(temp_array);
HttpContext.Current.Session["timestamp"] = value;
```

Now at ASMX decode like this.

```
[WebMethod]
public  string IsRowChanged(int en_id , string ts)
{
    byte[] timestamp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ts);
    // rest of your function here
}
```

Comment: @naveen The byte[] is a timestamp of sql server 2008. When i use linq to Entity i get it in a byte array.


Now First I need to convert a byte[] into a string so that i put it in a session object and later convert from string to byte[]. But i got different results when i compare the original byte array and the byte araay that was converted to a string and later cnverted to byte[]. Can you please post the code to convert a byte[] to string also.   I also have no knowledge of encoding i am using

Comment: can you show your code that converts the bytearray to string?

Comment: string str;
System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
str = enc.GetString(temp_array);
HttpContext.Current.Session["timestamp"] = str;

Comment: here is an example of using ASCII encoding and decoding. http://www.dijksterhuis.org/encoding-c-strings-as-byte-byte-arrays-and-back-again/